# Creating image in asp.net aspx.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am trying to create an image in asp.net then i want to change the image url in the code behind fie to display different images with different conditions. when i run the program i get an empty box with the description of the image. What should i do? thank you.

here is my code in the code behind file:

```
if (major2.Text == "ECE")
    {

        Image1.ImageUrl ="~/App_Data/Electrical_component.jpg";
        Image1.AlternateText = "ECE";
        Image1.Width = 250 ;
        Image1.Height = 250;
    }
    if (major2.Text == "ENG")
    {
        Image1.Width = 250;
        Image1.Height = 250;
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/App_Data/eng.jpg";
        Image1.AlternateText = "english";
    }
    if (major2.Text == "PHY")
    {
        Image1.Width = 250;
        Image1.Height = 250;
        Image1.AlternateText = "physics";
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/App_Data/PhysicsBanner.jpg";
    }
    if (major2.Text == "MEC")
    {

        Image1.Width = 250;
        Image1.Height = 250;
        Image1.AlternateText = "mechanical";
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/App_Data/mechanical-engineers_00062336.jpg";
    }
```

Comment: can you show all relevant code @SurayaNasser what method / event is the existing code in.. also can you explain the when and how you expect this code to be triggered ?also have you considered converting the If statement to a switch /case statement..?

Comment: @MethodMan the thing is the conditions are right so every time i give it the name of a student it fetches the major from the database and according to the major it displays the picture. it is doing that correctly because i can see the description changing according to the major. but the issue is that the picture is not showing

Comment: then you need to create a new instance of the Image control then assign the image url following that.. if this were a windows app it would work as you're expecting but rendering in asp.net is totally different or make sure that the image size is being updated correctly..

Comment: what event does the existing code reside in..? can you email me your code..?

Comment: Sure what is your email?

Answer (score 0):

Open up your webpage in Google Chrome, and open the F12 Developer Options  (I think this is the third time today I'm offering this advice to someone !!)

Go into the Network tab, then try to trigger one of your images appearing.

Does the Network tab show your webpage is trying to load the appropriate image file ?

If so, does it produce a "404" not found error, or does it successfully load that image ?

It's also worth checking that your image files have been set to "Copy to output" in Visual Studio, to make sure they are included in your site.  But if you hit a "404" error above, that'll point this problem out to you.

Finally, does your C# code (shown in the question) actually get run?  If you put a breakpoint on these lines, does it get hit ?   And does a Postback occur after setting the Image attributes, which might also explain the images disappearing again.

Good luck!

Comment: when i run this page alone the image is displayed. but when i am redirected to this page from another page the image is not displayed. so i dont think its google chrome

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with google chrome it think that it has to do with how you are redirecting and there is probably an error happening in your code prior to the redirect.. use the debugger to step through the code @SurayaNasser

Comment: the problem I believe was in the images path in her code I reviewed it off line and there were a couple of other small issues that I fixed for her.. I am waiting on her to respond to if the changes worked on her end.